# GRE: read from PTY failed error when connecting multiple clients to PPTP

Tags: vpn, centos5, pptp, gre

I have just installed a pptp server and now I can make it work. The problem is, it can only be connected to by one client. How do I set it up so that it will allow multiple users?

Here is the error log that is thrown after the second user tries to login..

```
Aug  5 23:28:14 vps1 pptpd[1570]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=611860,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
Aug  5 23:28:14 vps1 pptpd[1570]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
```

Comment: Have you loaded the modules ip_gre/ip_nat_pptp?

Comment: how do you do that? here is the steps i followed: http://freehostinganswers.com/blog/how-to-install-your-own-vpn-server-in-5-mins-pptp-on-centos-redhat-and-ubuntu/

Comment: It is working for the first user.. but cannot handle two users at once.

Comment: the same users (login)?

Comment: nope.. i've already created a second user but still only one of them would work at a time..

Comment: how do you load ip_nat_pptp anyway?

Comment: # modprobe ip_nat_pptp

Comment: seems like modprobe is not supported on openvz..

Answer (score 2):

I think root of the issue is openvz itself.

> The problem is, it can only be connected to **by one client**.

it seems that on the host system is not loaded module ip_nat_pptp/nf_nat_pptp. You could ask your hoster to do that.

Comment: yeah i already figured that out and gave up. will look for a host that offers Xen or KVM instead.. thanks! will give you +1 even if its not the solution. at least for others it would be clear that it is not possible.